# Reference for a density result on the space of differentiable functions vanishing at infinity

Tags: general-topology, analysis, reference-request

I would like to a reference (preferably a book) for the question in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497615/dense-subspace-of-the-space-of-functions-vanishing-at-infinity) topic when the functions are defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I googled a bit for a reference, but found none.  I expect that the required result can be proved as [proposed by Tsemo Aristide](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497615/dense-subspace-of-the-space-of-functions-vanishing-at-infinity/1497622#1497622), with the help of Stone-Weierstrass theorem and bump functions (see, for instance, Lemma 2.1 [here](http://web.math.ku.dk/~grubb/dist2.pdf)).